# Best local database for WPF Applications

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, database, vb.net

Referring to this question that's already been answer: 
"[What is the best local-database solution for WPF applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987243/what-is-the-best-local-database-solution-for-wpf-applications)"

What is currently my best choice of local database for my program? Currently I am using XML that is automatically created on the computer when the user run my executable for the first time or when the XML is missing.

I am perfectly fine on using XMLs, users of my application would not be required to install any software other than my application and I can do exactly with it, but my problem is with searching.

My application includes a database (the XML) of all their songs in their music library, and of course each track has its own information and search through each track is really slow! since it's a music library, one user can have at least 1000 tracks or more and searching through it is really really terrible.

I am familiar on using SQL database, (i don't know the proper term for it) but one for online database, I use XAMPP and read the database on a website on PHP. And i really like it. So..

Basically, I am looking for a good local-database solution, where user's won't to download and install any other software (but I am okay, if i would have to include a certain dll to my exe in other to run), and also one that is lightweight and fast in terms of searching.

Yes, i've read the included related question as many times as i could for me to understand it myself but i hope someone can explain the advantages and disad of each of them.

No, i am not looking for one that needs to have a server or something in order for it to work

Comment: This could be the one, thanks!

Comment: Mostly SQLite would be suggested, because it is the most widely known and thus would be perceived as 'best'. OTOH it depends on how you look at it and say "LiteDB" might also be called the 'best'. And there are others.

Comment: I am currently learning how SQLite works and i'm really enjoying and loving it! This could really be the one! Thanks!

Comment: Of course, one would say until he sees a NoSQL solution :) It is good for an SQL database. Keep in mind that it is for single user data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous suggestion is correct SQLite will be your best option because WPF operates .NET Framework. It also supports ODBC driver as i recall

Comment: I am currently learning how SQLite works and i'm loving it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was going to just comment but can't quite yet.

I wouldn't say there's necessarily a 'best' in most cases. In general whatever you go with is unlikely to be that bad of a choice..

Having said that, I could suggest [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) as an option for you. Lightweight, very fast, certainly good for strictly local-database options.

Comment: I will look it up! Thank you! I will get back to you within a day or so if this is the one I've been looking for, seriously Thanks!